# DevExpress LookUpEdit And Coded UI Tests

Tags: devexpress, coded-ui-tests

We are developing software using Windows Forms and DevExpress controls.

And also we want to use Coded UI tests to test our application automatically.

As our recent experiences taught us that DevExpress does not support CUIT.

But we have no options to neither give up from DevExpress control nor give up from CUIT.

Recently i created a test case using MTM that tests a form which includes LookUpEdit controls. As you would guess i couldn't use parameters correctly.

Is there any way to workaround this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `CustomAccessibleObject` for each of your controls that inherits from `Control.ControlAccessibleObject`. Then override the `CreateAccessibilityInstance()` method on your control so that it returns a `CustomAccessibleObject`.

In your control:

```
public class MyControl : SomeDevExpressControl  
{
    protected override AccessibleObject CreateAccessibilityInstance()
    {
        return new MyCustomAccessibleObject(this);
    }
}

public class MyCustomAccessibleObject : Control.ControlAccessibleObject
{
    //override stuff here
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.accessibleobject.aspx
 for more details.

Comment: i will try this as soon as possible. I hope it works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, DevExpress controls are supported by [TestComplete framework](http://www2.smartbear.com/tc-aw-int-testcomplete.html?gclid=CKn3h5KBmagCFUEb4QodOn8jDA).  We (at DevExpress) aren't aware of other frameworks which support our tools.  I am not familiar with the Coded UI framework and cannot help you to adapt it using our controls :(.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. As you said, DevExpress support TestComplete. But we have got Visual Studio license so we can use MTM and Coded UI; and we don't want to add extra cost with TestComplete. So i must find a way to accomplish this.