# using coded ui on infragistics winform controls

Tags: c#, infragistics, coded-ui-tests

I've recently decided to take a look at automated UI testing using vs2010's coded UI. However, I've come across some problems, namely a `FailedToPerformActionOnBlockedControlException` when playing back selecting a value from a combo box.

A quick search for this exception and infragistics and coded ui seems to say that there is no formal support for infragistics winform controls using coded ui however several websites has mentioned using coded ui extensions.

Has anyone had experience with successfully making coded ui recognise infragistics controls? such as the combo box, ultragrid etc...?

Comment: dude you know what screw infragistics it has a lot of problems with it's tabs, textboxes..use AJAX

Comment: @BurnAfterReading, this is a windows application so AJAX is not an option. Besides, i've used these infragistics controls throughout the whole app for better UI interaction, hardly an option for me to change the product for testing purposes

Answer (score 1):

My company uses our own controls that inherit from Infragistics controls. See this related question for tips which may help.

[DevExpress LookUpEdit And Coded UI Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645844/devexpress-lookupedit-and-coded-ui-tests)

Comment: thank you for the link. it looks quite development intensive. i realised that anything to do with 'coded' UI will need development since further searching seems to suggest that there just isn't anything written for infragistics controls. So i've gone a much simpler but less integrated path using AutoIT.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a robust solution for automated testing of Infragistics WinForms controls, and are willing to use a different tool, have a look at [Infragistics TestAdvantage](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/testadvantage.aspx#Overview), a plugin for HP QTP / IBM RFT.

Comment: I had a quick look at infragistics testadvantage but there is a lack of support and information out there, tutorials etc... which makes me hesitant to pick up so many new tools just for some simple testing. Have you had experience with any of these tools, how did you fare with them and what was the end result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RANOREX. It worked for most controls, for example the Ultragrid

See http://www.ranorex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Support for the CodedUITest framework is being looked at by Infragistics and a beta may be available late in Q1 of 2012.  There are more details in the following post:
http://blogs.infragistics.com/forums/p/10294/323529.aspx#323529

Answer (score 0):

Little update:

For Winforms there targetting to release support for CodedUI in their Netadvantage 2012 Volume 2 product.
Expected in October 2012